# Accessing new access-token upon reload from redux-token-auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, redux, devise-token-auth

I am building a web application consists of a React frontend and a couple of Rails APIs in the backend. One Rails API is for user authentication and the other is for storage, and all of this is coordinated through resftful API endpoints. For the client side authentication I am user redux-token-auth paired with the devise_token_auth gem on the user authentication API. On the storage API, it confirms the user is  authenticated by having the user authentication API send the client identifier and access-token to the storage API upon login. Following the client verifies the access-token and client identifier with the storage for authorization. Everything works, but the issue I am having is that upon reload of the client side application, a new token is generated, and this new token has to be sent and stored in the storage API for authorization to work.

I have looked into the code for redux-token-auth, and there is verifyCredentials function that gets called when the client reloads. This function seems to be a promise that does not return a promise. Further verifyCredentials calls verifyToken, which stores the access-token into local storage. But, this as well does not return a promise that I can get to. I have tried updating the access-token immediately after verifyCredentials is called and sending the new token via axios in the client side to the storage API, but it always sends the last token and not the newly updated token. I have tried doing this in various ways at various times in the application life cycle and have failed.

Is there any viable solution to this problem, or anyway to turn verifyToken/VerifyCrendials into a promise that return response data that I can access?

Answer (score 1):

Late, but try:

- axios interceptors: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1383
- plus fetching the token from localStorage (`localStorage.getItem('...')`